# iOS watchkit extension import no longer works

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, watchkit

I have been working on a watch and phone app off and on for the past year without updating Xcode.  I finished the app and it was working perfectly.

Today I updated xcode to the latest version and converted my Swift code to the latest Swift in Xcode so I could put it on the App Store.

Many things broke.  I've managed to fix the syntax updates etc.. however now a class I was using to share data between the phone and watch will not import any more.  The phone section imports it fine, but the watchkit extension gives me the error `no such module DataProxyKit`.  I can't figure out what has gone wrong.  Any suggestions appreciated.

[image: error message]